# Tablet screen brightness on Panasonic CF-H2

Tags: touchscreen

I've just started using the Beaver on a [Panasonic CF-H2](https://www.porterelectronics.com/panasonic-toughbook-cf-h2/) and I have no control of the screen brightness. It seems that the slider in the access menu isn't adjusting.

Is there a fix?

Comment: Can you add the hardware specs.